# How do you play two different song files on python at the same time?

Tags: python, python-2.4, myro

I'm trying to play song1 and song2 (the commented out one) at the same time, but I don't know how to do that using myro or winsound or whatever it is. Someone suggested using threading, but I'm not sure how to do that either, since I am just a very baby beginner programmer. Would someone please help me figure this thing out and/or explain in detail how to do this? Here's what I have so far:

```
import winsound
from myro import *
def main():

    HftM1 = makeSong("Db4 3/8; C4 3/8; Bb3 1/4; Bb3 3/8; Ab3 3/8; Gb3 3/8; Ab3 1/16; C4 3/8; Bb3 3/8; Ab3 1/8; Eb3 1/16; F3 1/16; Ab3 3/8; G3 3/8; F3 3/8; C4 1/16; Db4 3/8; C4 3/8; Bb3 1/8; F3 1/16; Gb3 1/16; Bb3 3/8; Ab3 3/8; Gb3 3/8; C4 3/8; Bb3 3/8; Ab3 1/8; Eb3 1/16; F3 1/16; Ab3 3/8; G3 3/8; F3 3/8")

    saveSong(HftM1, "HymnfortheMissing1.txt", append=1)

    HftM2 = makeSong("Bb2 1/8; F3 1/8; Bb3 1/4; Bb2 1/8; F3 3/8; Gb2 1/8; Db3 1/8; Gb3 1/4; Gb2 1/8; Db3 3/8; Ab2 1/8; Eb3 1/8; Ab3 1/4; Ab2 1/8; Eb3 3/8; F2 1/8; C3 1/8; F3 1/4; F2 1/8; C3 3/8; Bb2 1/8; F3 1/8; Bb3 1/4; Bb2 1/8; F3 3/8; Gb2 1/8; Db3 1/8; Gb3 1/4; Gb2 1/8; Db3 3/8; Ab2 1/8; Eb3 1/8; Ab3 1/4; Ab2 1/8; Eb3 3/8; F2 1/8; C3 1/8; F3 1/4; F2 1/8; C3 3/8")

    saveSong(HftM2, "HymnfortheMissing2.txt", append=1)

    song1 = readSong("HymnfortheMissing1.txt")

    #song2 = readSong("HymnfortheMissing2.txt") #This part of the song is supposed to be played at the same time as the first part, but I don't know how to do that so...

    play = []

    for n in range(len(song1)):
        play = song1[n]
        note = play[0]
        duration = play[1]
        winsound.Beep(int(note), int(duration*2000))
main()
```

Comment: You asked this exact question a few days ago.

Comment: @Blender I know (duh). The answers I got were not very helpful (for me anyways) so I took it down and re-posted with a little more detail hoping to get some better ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) for this kind of work, and check out this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004887/in-pygame-how-is-it-if-even-possible-to-play-more-than-one-song). You'd have to use the mixer module.

In general you would have to mix the PCM data using some mathematical manipulation on the audio streams (for an example discussion [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089662/mixing-16-bit-linear-pcm-streams-and-avoiding-clipping-overflow)).

---

**Update**: Myro (which I have never used) says [in the docs](http://wiki.roboteducation.org/Myro_Reference_Manual#Output_Functions) that there is a way to do this using the `beep` function:

> beep(self, duration, frequency, frequency2 = None): make a tone. If
>   two tones are given, the robot will combine them.

As a simple example, if you have note A, duration 1 second in the first song, and note B, duration 2 seconds in the second song you will have to call `beep` twice: First to play both notes A and B simultaneously for 1 second, and then to play only note B for another 1 second.

Needless to say, this code will be much more complicated than just playing sounds from audio files using something like PyGame and mixing them.

Comment: I've checked out the related question already. As for the rest, I am way to much of a baby programmer to know how to do that. I haven't even looked at PyGame yet, so I'll have to have a little more simplicity and/or detail.

Comment: I've added a link to `myro` which claims it can be done using their library.

Comment: Yes, but this program is reading a song file. Thus the "saveSong(HftM1, "HymnfortheMissing1.txt", append=1)" part of the code. That would only work if I was trying to just combine two different tones. I am trying to basically combine two different sheets of music or sets of tones.

Comment: You can use the `beep` function on the songs after they are converted to tones. That is, use it in your loop at the end instead of calling `winsound.Beep`. You'll have to write some logic that figures out how to split the lengths of each tone in case where one song is changing a tone while the other is still playing the older tone. If you don't *have* to use the song files in that format, I recommend you just switch to pygame. Check out some of [these pygame tutorials](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/tutorials) to get started.

Comment: You're saying change "for n in range(len(song1)):
        play = song1[n]
        note = play[0]
        duration = play[1]
        winsound.Beep(int(note), int(duration*2000))" to: "for n in range(len(song2)):
        play = song1[n], song2[n]
        note = play[0]
        duration = play[1]
        beep(int(note), int(duration*2000))"?

Comment: No, you need to use all the information from both songs (both frequency and duration). I suggest you think about the problem at hand in general terms before trying to program it.

Comment: I don't think you can put that much information into a beep function. Besides, the beep function uses frequency, the song function uses notes and octaves.

Comment: I've added an example of how you could do it.