# How do I use the multiprocess library with winsound in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am writing a basic piano style program that uses functions with winsound.Beep to play different note. I am new to multi-processing, and was wondering how I would be able to play two notes at once. If that is not possible, perhaps there is a way to combine frequencies that I do not know. Thanks for reading
~Jimnebob

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you play two different song files on python at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902336/how-do-you-play-two-different-song-files-on-python-at-the-same-time)

Comment: This isn't the same! I'm using winsound.Beep, and hes using a sound file

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Beep function couldn't play several notes at the same time. You can record the sound of 'Beep' through sounddevice library, save the sound in wav files. Then, use subprocess.Popen to achieve multiprocess. The subprocess would play the wav files.